# Revert combo.SelectedItem to its last value causes StackOverflow

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've been asked to allow the user to (try to) change the selected value in the combobox event when its not valid. When he does so, I have to show an alert, and revert the SelectedItem of the combobox to its previous value.

I have something like:

```
private void cmbCountry_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
            Country selectedCountry = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem as Country;

            if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && !canChange)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
                return;
            }

            // Do stuff...
}
```

The problem is, although I set the `e.Handled = true;` The SelectionChanged event keeps firing giving me a StackOverflowException...

I guess its a common problem...

Do I have an elegant way of solving this?

Comment: If you're using MVVM you might want to take a look at IDataErrorInfo for data validation. [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx) would be a nice article to get you started if you are interested.

Comment: I could understand this as an academic exercise, but I'd consider it poor UI design to have selectable options that are inherently invalid. Better to disable the items (although this may be bugged for some use cases: http://blog.elgaard.com/2009/09/03/wpf-making-combo-box-items-disabled-also-when-accessed-using-the-keyboard), or filter the ComboBox ItemsSource collection to remove any currently invalid options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you checked that your overall logic is correct as suggested by @nvoigt you may use this as a brute force trick:

```
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && canChange)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            canChange = false; // avoid infinite recursion
            ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
            canChange = true; // reset to original value
            return;
        }
```

This way the handler code is not called again from within the handler code.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your SelectedItem in the ChangeHandler for the SelectedItem, you have an infinite recursion. The `Handled` flag only says *this* change was handled. For the *new* change you created, this function is called again.

The question is why is *your* change triggering your logic again? Shouldn't your change be the valid change? You will need to debug your program. Set a breakpoint and step through your method until you know what's wrong when you hit it a second time.